# Print Element in Dictonary

Tags: python, printing

Hey i have a question how i can print a specific element in a Dictonary without a loop

i tryed this code but this dosnt work :(

```
dict = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "song": "Song5",
            "time": 1660582745,
            "info": "he"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "song": "Song4",
            "time": 1660568345,
            "info": "heheheh"
        }
    ]
}


print(dict["data"]["time"])
```

i need this output

```
1660582745, 1660568345
```

this works but i need it without loop

```
for i in data["data"]:
    print(i["time"])

output:
    1660582745
    1660568345
```

Comment: One way or another, you're going to need some sort of loop.

Comment: Why do you not want a loop? Do you only always have two items to get? You can get your output using a loop, if that's the actual question.

Comment: How could you even design this without a loop, let alone implement it? Unless you literally want to write the same code over and over again except each one having one higher index number. That would be a huge pain though and terrible practice. Does the data absolutely have to be in this format? Is the data's length fixed? If not then even my suggestion wouldn't work

Comment: is there a reason you dont want to use a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically without a "for" loop, using `map` and `operator.itemgetter`

*(this still iterates the list though)* Also don't overwrite builtins such as `dict`. Here I use `my_dict` as the name.

```
from operator import itemgetter

my_dict = { ... }

print(*map(itemgetter("time"), my_dict["data"]))
```

Result:

```
1660582745 1660568345
```

You could also use a comprehension if loops are ok.

```
[d["time"] for d in my_dict["data"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with static list element e.g 0 and 1, if you only always have two items to get then you can do this way, **But why don't you want a loop?**

```
print(dict["data"][0]["time"])
print(dict["data"][1]["time"])
```

But if you have an arbitrary size then this wouldn't be possible.In that case your existing looping way should do the trick.

```
for item in data["data"]:
    print(item["time"])
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that this will only work for a list with a known size; if it's an arbitrary size then this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Yes, agreed, going to update the answer to inform that.

Comment: Bacause with the loop i cant enter to the correct index i need but you example helped me :D

Comment: @Crypto that doesn't make sense; you need to show an example of why that's the case. A loop has nothing to do with one's ability to index into a list. Simply stating that that's the reason isn't proof enough that what you're saying is actually the case.

Answer (score 0):

soo okay its working here the code

json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "song": "Song5",
            "time": "1660582745",
            "info": "he"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "song": "Song4",
            "time": "1660568345",
            "info": "heheheh"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "song": "Song3",
            "time": "1660546745",
            "info": "lololol"
        }
    ]
}
```

python code

```
import json
import datetime


def sort_json():
    data = False
    with open('data.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    now = 1660582985

    temp = []
    sortedlist = []

    for i in data["data"]:
        temp.append(int(i["time"]) - now)

    sortedlist = sorted(temp, key = lambda i: 0 if i == 0 else -1 / i)

    for sort in sortedlist:
        print(data["data"][temp.index(sort)]["song"])


sort_json()
```

Comment: I don't understand, why ask with the constraint of not using a loop then answer your question using a loop and that loop is exactly what you said you didn't want?

Comment: so if i use a loop i need to loop thought sortedlist and inside this loop i need to loop thought the dict with data["data"][temp.index(sort)]["song"] i can directly navigate to the element i need without looping thought the dict

Comment: It seems like you asked a very different question from what you wanted solved.

Comment: im sorry for misunderstanding